# Create a script to download images from Syntax tree generator

Tags: php, html, image, download

I'm working with a language school and I need to download a large number of images generated using this tool: http://mshang.ca/syntree/
I downloaded it, customized the tool a little but I can't find a way of automatically download all the images generated.
I'm using URL to create the images:

```
http://mshang.ca/syntree/index.html?i=[བྱ་ཚིག་དང་ཡག [ཕྱེད་བརྗོད་པ [ཅ་ལག་ཉོ་]] [ཡག་ [ཡག་]] [བྱ་ཚིག་ཕལ་པ། [དངུལ་མེད། ]]]
```

Do you have any ideas on how I should modify the source code or how should I write the script?

Thanks

Zopa

PS: I'm on linux so any bash script is fine too...

Comment: Where do you need to download them from, and do you have a list of them?

Comment: yes I have a file with a list of URLs in it